# Is it possible to compile latex to pdf on heroku server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, latex, tex-live

I need to compile the latex to pdf on heroku node.js server. The problem is that we need to install texlive for exec command.

Comment: I don't know these things, but if you know read a latex file, probably you may use `substr`, `indexOf`, `lastIndexOf` and `replace` to get values in file and do a new PDF from the latex. :S If the file is compiled, then you have to find something for JS that also can help to decompile it.

Comment: @ProHands I know how to install telive. But i dont know: is it possible to do it on heroku server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Heroku is running Debian/Ubuntu Linux, yes.
You might be looking for a lean installation, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66348/latex-minimal-installation-in-gnu-linux-distributions-e-g-in-ubuntu-and-using).

Comment: In Heroku you do not have an access to terminal.

Comment: But you can run a bash in the console. I didn't do it myself, but it all boils down to opening a shell, pushing the distro onto the server and running the installer. See also here: http://www.saintsjd.com/2014/05/12/run-vendored-binaries-on-heroku.html.